# Sequelize op.like don`t working correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I recently came across a database job in `node`.

Currently I have a problem related with the `Sequelize` request.

There is a simple code, and there `op.like` gives out incorrect `sql` query.

Instead of `%delay%`  in the request we have `'\"%delay%\"'`.

Here is the code piece and the response from server

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const shortcodes = await Shortcode.findAll({
      where: {
           project_id: project.id,
             settings: {
                 [Op.like]: `%delay%`
             }
           }
      });
```

Here is the `Sql` query created by this library.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `shortcodes` AS `shortcode`
WHERE `shortcode`.`project_id` = 1
  AND `shortcode`.`settings` LIKE '\"%delay%\"';
```

Comment: Can you try changing SQL dialect? May be it's a bug the particular dialect you are using. (Also, this probably won't work, but it's worth a shot... try changing `\`%delay%\`` to `'%delay%'`)

Comment: Try to use variable instead of `%delay%`: [Op.like]: `%${delayVar}%`

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Not workig.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in library... so you can also try: 1) using newer version 2) trying out MSSQL dialect, since it's most different from mysql

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek I tried the latest version as well before asking the question.

Comment: You can also try: `[Op.substring]: 'delay'`

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek nor working)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the whole internet came across one person's `github` profile.

Which had roughly the same problem.

And as I understood this is a bug of the `Sequelize` library.

Here is the solution to this problem.

Modified and working code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const shortcodes = await Shortcode.findAll({
      where: {
           project_id: project.id,
             settings: {
                 [Op.like]: Sequelize.literal('\'%delay%\'')
             }
           }
      });
```

Here is the correct generated `sql` query.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `shortcodes` AS `shortcode`
WHERE `shortcode`.`project_id` = 1
  AND `shortcode`.`settings` LIKE '%delay%';
```

Here is the [resource](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12073) from where I read all this.